# View Grails configuration at runtime

Tags: grails, jmx, grails-plugin

Is it possible to view your Grails configuration (i.e. properties in your Config.groovy) anyway at all at runtime via JMX (or any other way)?

Before going off writing something to do this, I just wanted to check what is the grails way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask? Do you just want to display all the set properties in a gsp?

Comment: Would prefer to do it via JMX.

Comment: Where do you want to see these config? Showing all the config properties anywhere in the app can be easily achieved by just using `grailsApplication.config`, it can also be tested by executing this one line in grails console. It gives a map representation of all the config properties. It is still unclear where do you want this information. It will also be clear if you add "why is it needed" to the context of the question?